# How to Check Associativity for Higher Order Groups, for example, Quaternion Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Quaternion group, $(Q_8, .)$ is defined by

$Q_8= \{1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k\}$

And the binary operation $\cdot$ is defined as follows:

$\forall a\in Q,  1\cdot a=a\cdot 1=a, (-1)\cdot a=a\cdot (-1)=-a$ and $(-1)\cdot (-1)=1$

$i\cdot i=j\cdot j=k\cdot k=-1$

$i\cdot j=k, j\cdot k=i, k\cdot i=j$

$j\cdot i=-k, k\cdot j=-i, i\cdot k=-j$

---

I need to show that the binary operation $.$ follows the law of associativity. I cannot thought of checking $8^3=512$ cases. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no "slick tricks" that I know of. The best I can think of is to show $Q_8$ is a subgroup of a group that's easier to verify. For instance, can you find 8 elements of a symmetric group, or 8 matrices, which satisfy the desired relations?

Comment: The MSE post I've linked above gives a couple of ideas - I wish I had a better answer :/ Some things are just tedious, unfortunately...

Comment: Well here (8+8-1)+(7+7-1)+3+6=37 cells of Cayley Table is defined. If we define rest 27 cells using associativity, then is this guaranteed that all 512 combination will follow associativity?

For example, $i.(-j)= i.((-1).j)= (i.j)(-1)= k.(-1)=-k$